# Opencv fillPoly() not working for greyscale (1-channel) images

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0

so I am using opencv to modify pixel values on a 1-channel image.
I create the blank image using

```
curr = np.zeros((660,512, 1))
```

then execute the code:

```
for r in regions:
    cv2.fillPoly(curr, r, [190])
```

where each region looks something like:

```
[[[363 588]
  [304 593]
  [323 652]
  [377 654]]]
```

I know that the code is at least somewhat working, because when I use imshow(), the regions are filled as desired.  However, I tried re-accessing the modified pixel values, and got [ 0.]  I tried writing the whole img ti a temporary file as follows:

```
for elt in curr:
    f2.write(str(elt) + '\n')
```

However, the file just looks like

```
 [ 0.]
 [ 0.]
 [ 0.]
 [ 0.]
 [ 0.]
 [ 0.]
 [ 0.]
 [ 0.]
 [ 0.]
 [ 0.]
 [ 0.]
 [ 0.]
```

Where am I going wrong?  Why can't I re-access the 190s I wrote to the image?

Answer (score 2):

maybe you are over-writing or re-initialising image(curr) somewhere in the code, here's the code using `cv2.imwrite` to save the file.

```
curr = np.zeros((660,512, 1))
regions = np.random.uniform(1, 200, size=(1, 5, 2))
regions = regions.astype(np.int32, copy=False)
for r in regions:
    cv2.fillPoly(curr, [r], [190])

while(1):
    cv2.imshow('Terry Martin', curr)
    k= cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        cv2.imwrite('FillPloy.jpg', curr)
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

OpenCV Window:
[image]

Output image:
[image]

Comment: As I said, displaying the image in a window; it looks just fine.  But I want to then be able to look at the file, and find the max value.  
As an alternative, I tried writing the image to a file as a png, then opening the saved file using imread.  Now I got [190, 190, 190] as the max value in the image.  Is this just what I should expect from a greyscale image?  I thought because the image shape was (660, 512, 1), accessing an individual pixel would give me a singular value.  But accessing img[x][y] always returns a 3 element array.

Answer (score 1):

Works just fine.

```
curr = np.zeros((660,512, 1),dtype = np.uint8)

regions = np.array([[[363,588],[304,593],[323,652],[377,654]]])

for r in regions:
    cv2.fillPoly(curr, [regions[0]], (190))

# find minimum value, maximum value and their location index in the image
minVal,maxVal,minLoc,maxLoc = cv2.minMaxLoc(curr)

print(maxVal, maxLoc)
```